# SagePay IFrame loads the Response URL in IFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc, opayo

We implemented SagePay in our .NET MVC project with IFrame method. However we are facing an issue with the response redirection.

After the successful payment via sage pay all the responses are loading within the IFrame itself. Where as we would like to redirect the response in the parent window itself.

We also noted that in the demo .NET Sage Kit, the redirection is happening correctly with the following code.

Response.Write(string.Format("RedirectURL={0}server/Result.aspx?Status={1}&VendorTxCode={2}", SagePaySettings.SiteFqdn, serverNotificationRequest.Status, serverNotificationRequest.VendorTxCode));

In our MVC frame work, we are also forming the url in the same format with a slightly different code, that is,

context.HttpContext.Response.Output.WriteLine("RedirectURL={0}PaymentResponse/Success?Status=OK&VendorTxCode={1}", SagePaySettings.SiteFqdn, response.VendorTxCode);

Could you please help us to solve this issue.

Comment: I did some work integrating Sage payments a while ago, and found that the responses wouldn't work with the MVC url structure, so I had to use .aspx pages for the responses, as per the examples.

Comment: It is the responsibility of your final result page to break out of the iframe. Just making that clear for other people reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it happen I used, ContentResult for the action to update the parent URL.

```
return new ContentResult
            {

                Content = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.location.href = '{0}';</script>", newurl),
                ContentType = "text/html"
            };
```

Comment: hi,i am also try to implement i frame with asp.net MVC 5.0. but i am getting error. "NO parameter with action method...". Could you try to share your findings?

Comment: I guess you are trying to call any actions with invalid params. I am not sure because I di not see your actual code.

Comment: I use the SagePay.dll which is available on Nuget. but i think that it has sum bug with MVC 4 or 5. if you use different approach, would you share the details information about it, or from where should i get information, how to integrate using MVC.

Comment: Dear Humayoo, we went with Iframe integration, you can find samples in their website.

Comment: are you using asp.net web form or asp.net MVC?  i have problem with mvc. there is no example of MVC on their website. they have example of asp.net web form. could your share the i frame MVC sample of link from their website?